# Where is ENS deployed?

Tags: ens

ENS is a deployed contract. Where is it?

Specification: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-137.md

And why didn't they specify that in the EIP?

Answer (score 3):

EIP-137 is a specification that anyone can follow should they want to implement their own EIP-137-compliant ENS service. (Think private networks, etc.)

To that end, it must remain agnostic towards specific implementations. By including the the address of the ENS team's deployed contract, that agnosticism would be lost, and it would no longer be a specification.

The ENS team's deployed registrar contract can be found [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef). EtherScan has an ENS portal, which can be found at: https://etherscan.io/ens (URL included in full deliberately... ) From there you can follow incoming transactions through to the registrar contract.

Comment: Arguably, the eth registry is only tangentially connected to the ENS spec. Without more clarification, I would say that the ENS contract is the registry, hosted at https://etherscan.io/address/0x314159265dd8dbb310642f98f50c066173c1259b as mentioned here http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/introduction.html#ens-on-ethereum